# How to edit a .js file that is created/referenced by a rubygem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've got a .js file that I'd like to edit but I cannot find it because it's loaded by a rubygem.  Is there a way to access this file to edit?

Comment: It depends on the gem. But for the most part it's usually a No.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the gem by running `bundle open foo` which will open the gem directory in your editor. You could go and modify the content you want there (the location of the file may vary, but look in the vendor folder of the gem). However, this is probably a bad idea, since you would only work locally and you would likely lose your changes when you upgraded the gem. The more viable solution would be to fork the gem, make your changes there and then include your forked version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'foo', git: 'http://github.com/your_repo/foo.git'
```